# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document - are COM calls to this object async or sync?

Tags: c#, .net, com

I am attempting to extract RTF code out of a word instance that my .NET C# application launches. The code that performs this is:

```
Clipboard.Clear();
//document is of type Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
document.Application.Activate();
document.Select();
document.Content.Copy();

if (Clipboard.ContainsData(DataFormats.Text) && 
    Clipboard.ContainsData(DataFormats.Rtf))
{
    DocumentContent = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf);
}
Clipboard.Clear();
```

What is periodically happening is that when the call is made to Clipboard.GetText it is returning String.Empty. So I was wondering if it is possible that the COM call to the Content.Copy has not finished yet. The reason I suspect this is because if I put a break point on DocumnetContent=...   and it comes back as String.Empty I can just move the debugger back one line and call the GetText line again and this time it will contain the text. Similarly if it comes back with String.Empty I can go into notepad and hit control+V and it will paste the copied text that I expect to be on the clipboard.

I must stress that this behavior is not consistent. I can't reproduce it at will but if I perform the action enough (usually 1 out of 20 will trigger this behavior) I'll eventually get it.

Thank you for your help and please let me know of any clarifications needed.

Comment: Office programs are multi-threaded programs by themselves, doing their best to not freeze the UI.  Dumping a gazillion bytes on the clipboard is not something they ever discourage, users just expect it to work.  Lots of tricks that make *that* come to a good end, delayed rendering is one of them.  I suspect you are missing out on them.  Nothing pretty to fix btw.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but how does delayed rendering help my situation? In my example the page has already rendered and I'm actually leaving the page and trying to capture what was typed by the user in the word control. If you could provide a bit more detail or an article that would be very helpful. Thank you for the comment.